# android How to get image path from GridView through onItemClick listener

Tags: android

Got stuck a bit since i cannot understand how to get the path from 
a picture i click in the GridView.

This listener is the problem since i load the GridView with images from a folder on the sdcard.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

I can only see example on how to use the "position" when the GridView is loaded from resources.

Can anyone give me a hint how to do this.
Im reading and trying this

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
projection,
null, 
null, 
null)
```

But that will give me all images from sdcard root.
My folder is "sdcard/PTPPservice"

I will from here send an intent to show the image like:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
      intent.putExtra("filename", imagePath);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution, so i answer my own quesion.
The orgPath is a string i added and saves the path during loadind of images

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {    

    ImageAdapter i = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
    LoadedImage l = (LoadedImage)i.getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImage.class);
    intent.putExtra("filename", l.orgPath);
    startActivity(intent);
    return;

}
```

Comment: It´s the [custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475434/how-to-use-an-arrayadapter-in-android-of-custom-objects) in the adapter

Comment: OK but add it in a note, so people will not get confused