# how to use an ArrayAdapter in android of custom objects

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

How can I use the properties of a custom object in a Listview. If I implement an ArrayAdapter with a list of Strings it displays fine in Listview but when I use a list of custom objects, it just outputs the memory address.

The code I have up to now:

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> allObjects = new ArrayList<>();

allObjects.add("title", "http://url.com"));


  ArrayAdapter<NewsObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NewsObject>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, allNews);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" );
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
            }
        });
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593574/adding-a-custom-object-to-an-arrayadapter-how-to-grab-data) but that is not what I need since I just need to have the title show in list view and when they click extract the url.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

An ArrayAdapter displays the value returned by the `toString()` method, so you will need to override this method in your custom Object class to return the desired String. You will also need to have at least a getter method for the URL, so you can retrieve that in the click event.

```
public class NewsObject {
    private String title;
    private String url;

    public NewsObject(String title, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
    ...
}
```

In the `onItemClick()` method, `position` will be the index in the ArrayList of your custom Objects corresponding to the list item clicked. Retrieve the URL, parse it, and call `startActivity()`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            NewsObject item = allNews.get(position);
            String url = item.getUrl();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    });
```

Please note, I assumed your custom class is `NewsObject`, as that is what's used with your Adapter example.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a methods of your custom class you need to implement a custor ArrayAdapter class... How to create this?

**First step**

Get your project and create a new class. Then extends class with `ArrayAdapter<YourObject>{}` and declare inside your atributes that you needs... My example:

```
public class Room_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Room_Object> {

//Declaration of Atributes
private ArrayList<Room_Object> Rooms_Array;
private final Activity context;
private final ListView lvBuinding;
```

**Second**

Declare a constructor for this class, always you need an Activity and ArrayList, put inside the others if you need... In my case I needs the listview... My example:

```
public Room_Adapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Room_Object> Rooms_Array,ListView lvBuinding) {
    super(context, R.layout.room_layout, Rooms_Array);

    this.context = context;
    this.Rooms_Array = Rooms_Array;
    this.lvBuinding = lvBuinding;
}
```

The super method nees your activity, custom layout (if you have it) and your array.

**Third**

Declare a static class or create a new one if you have a custom row layout. My example have a static class:

```
public static class Room_View{

    //Declaration of Atributes
    TextView RoomName;
    ImageView RoomState;
    TextView NoTroubles;

    Button btnRoomRow;

    ImageButton btnShowRoomTasks;
    ImageButton btnAddTasks;

    RelativeLayout RowLayout;
}
```

**Fourth**

Override method getView.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Declaration of Variables
    Room_View rowView; //Custom static class with controls
    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (ConvertView == null) {
        rowView = new Room_View();
        ConvertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.room_layout,null,true); //Inflate your view with your custom view.


        rowView.RoomName = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvRoom);
        rowView.RoomState = (ImageView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.ivRoomState);
        rowView.NoTroubles = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvNoTroubles);

        rowView.btnRoomRow = (Button) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRoomRow);

        rowView.btnAddTasks = (ImageButton) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddTask);
        rowView.btnShowRoomTasks = (ImageButton) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowRoomTasks);

        rowView.RowLayout = (RelativeLayout) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);


        ConvertView.setTag(rowView);
    }
    else
    {
        rowView = (Room_View) ConvertView.getTag();
    }

    //Here custom your control stats
    Room_Object Room = Rooms_Array.get(position);
    rowView.RoomName.setText(Room.getRoomName());

    rowView.NoTroubles.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rowView.btnShowRoomTasks.setClickable(true);
    rowView.btnShowRoomTasks.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_3a4b66_50);
    rowView.btnShowRoomTasks.setOnClickListener(OnShowTasksClickListener);

    //This is for add ClickListiner in my buttons...
    rowView.btnAddTasks.setOnClickListener(OnAddTasksClickListener);
    rowView.btnRoomRow.setOnClickListener(OnAddTasksClickListener);

    if(Room.getStatus().equals("Checked")){
        rowView.RowLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFC7E6C7);
        rowView.btnShowRoomTasks.setClickable(false);
        rowView.btnShowRoomTasks.setImageResource(R.drawable.list_999999_50);
        rowView.RoomState.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_3ebf4b_50);
    }
    else if(Room.getStatus().equals("Blocked")){
        rowView.RowLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFDBC3E5);
        rowView.RoomState.setImageResource(R.drawable.key_9330e0_50);
    }
    else if(Room.getStatus().equals("Dirty")){
        rowView.RowLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xfffceedb);
        rowView.RoomState.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_housekeeping_3_yellow);
    }
    else if(Room.getStatus().equals("Troubled")){
        rowView.RowLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF4CECD);
        rowView.RoomState.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrench_eb3232_50);

        rowView.NoTroubles.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            rowView.NoTroubles.setText(Integer.toString(Room.getNoTasks()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e("-- Error --",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //
    //Pay attention *************************************************
    //

    //Now if you needs to use your custom external class this is the site, now imagine that you need gets string from your custom class in the text view, then:

    //Declare class
    CustomClass object = new CustomClass();

    rowView.(CUSTOM CONTROL FROM YOUR STATIC CLASS).(METHOD OF CONTROL)(object.(CUSTOM METHOD OF YOUR OBJECT));

    //For example If you follows my sample then:
    rowView.NoTroubles.setText(object.getNumberOfTroubles().toString);


    return ConvertView;
}

//Listener Methods for my button controls
private View.OnClickListener OnShowTasksClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int positionSelected = lvBuinding.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        int totalRooms = lvBuinding.getCount() - 1;
        int actualRoom = totalRooms - positionSelected;

        try{
            //Your code;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e("-- CustomError --", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener OnAddTasksClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int positionSelected = lvBuinding.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        int totalRooms = lvBuinding.getCount() - 1;
        int actualRoom = totalRooms - positionSelected;

        try{
            //Your code;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e("-- CustomError --", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
}
```

I think this is that you needs, if you need more info or same advice me and I try to helps you... Good luck, Eduardo!

Answer (score 1):

@mike Answer can be short. `ArrayAdapter<Item>` `Item` class should override `toString()`

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
```

and you done

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                CustomObject obj = allObjects.get(position);
                //Now use obj to access the property
                Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" );
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the getView of your Adaptor to display the individual object at a position into your view.