# problems with ListViews (Android Studio)

Tags: xml, listview, android-listview, android-studio

I have two problems in making a `ListView` in Android studio, first of all, I have
a layout in which I want to make a `ListView` with around 100 elements that I can click on and
take me to another layout.

**1.** This is the content of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff7e00">


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my Preview, next to the XML code, a list of default elements appear, but when I test it
in the emulator, is not there, why?

**2.** I don't know how to edit the `ListView` in the java file, and how to set the number of
elements I want there to be, and how to make them lead me to a respective layout.

Comment: `numColumns` attribute is for `GridView` not for `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

Hi pdsafs df apk I answer post with similar problem do a long time, my post it's complet read this, when I said a custom layout, you need to create a layout for all rows, if yout need a list view that contains in each rows one button and two text views then create a layout with this controls and put this layout inside adapter with this code that you can find in this url:
[how to use an ArrayAdapter in android of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475434/how-to-use-an-arrayadapter-in-android-of-custom-objects/27480269#27480269)

In this post you can find too how create a correct click event in listview or other methods or controls!!

You need to declare your custom adapter in MainActivity, example:

```
//Declaration of variables
Custom_Adapter adapter = new Custom_Adapter(getActivity(), yourParams... );

//Put adapter inside listview
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please after that post a new Question find a little in this big community a lot of people programming with android and u can find a similar problems... I wait I can helps pdsafs df apk with my answer, and remember help this community with give a check for a correct answer or points if the people helps you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This may sound daunting at first, but it's not too bad. You're going to create an `ArrayList` with the data you want to populate each row with. Then, using an `ArrayAdapter`, you'll populate the `ArrayList` and fill up a custom layout. Then, you'll want to override the `getView()` method and have it add an `onClickListener` to each layout that'll take it to the respective class that you provide.

While I could provide code, it really isn't necessary, as Android provides a step-by-step tutorial on how to do this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: I will do that, thanks, but I still don't know why was my layout not seen in the emulator.

Comment: No errors, With that I placed in the xml file, the Preview showed me a list of elements, I went to the emulator expecting to see the list, but I didn't

Comment: The preview is just an example screen. By specifying the `tools:listitem` attribute, you are simply asking the IDE to render what that layout would look IF you used that layout in code.  Even if you didn't specify that attribute, it's normal for the preview screen to show some random content filling the `ListView`. It's simply to show how it may look. It bears no meaning to what you will actually see when running the app.