# ListView with 2 TextViews

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-ion

i am trying to post a certain message per item with 2 Textviews, however the ListView on accepts 1 adapter and shows the data given by that adapter

[image: the current view]

the Screenshot shows that the data from the database has been retrieved and put in de ListView only the Small Text Data is missing.

Code:

```
public class ReservationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    

List<String> subTextList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reservations);
    listReservations = (ListView)
    findViewById(R.id.listReservationsView);}

public void getReservations() {
        subTextList = new ArrayList<>();
        titleList = new ArrayList<>();
        titleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.title, titleList);
        subTextAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.subText, subTextList);
        listReservations.setAdapter(subTextAdapter);
        listReservations.setAdapter(titleAdapter);

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ReservationsActivity.this);
                String accessToken = prefs.getString("accessToken", null);
                String web_adres = getString(R.string.web_adres);
                String ip_adres = getString(R.string.ip_adres);
                Ion.with(ReservationsActivity.this)
                        .load(web_adres + "/reservations?accessToken=" + accessToken)
                        .proxy(ip_adres, 8080)
                        .asJsonArray()
                        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonArray result) {

                                jsonArray = result;
                                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                                    JsonObject jsonObject = result.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                                    JsonObject date = jsonObject.get("date").getAsJsonObject();
                                    JsonObject time = jsonObject.get("time").getAsJsonObject();
                                    String title = date.get("dayOfMonth").toString() + "/"
                                            + date.get("monthValue").toString() + "/"
                                            + date.get("year").toString();
                                    String subtext;
                                    if (time.get("id").getAsInt() == 1) {
                                        subtext = getString(R.string.morning);
                                        //imageInt = R.drawable.parking_morning;
                                    } else if (time.get("id").getAsInt() == 2) {
                                        subtext = getString(R.string.afternoon);
                                        //imageInt = R.drawable.parking_afternoon;
                                    } else if (time.get("id").getAsInt() == 3) {
                                        subtext = getString(R.string.day);
                                        //imageInt = R.drawable.parking_fullday;
                                    } else
                                        subtext = getString(R.string.day);


                                    titleAdapter.add(title);
                                    subTextAdapter.add(subtext);
                                    //TODO set Image per item
                                    //image.setImageResource(imageInt);
                                    titleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    subTextAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }
```

how would one make it so that it populates all the items?

Answer (score 0):

Following might help you:

- You need to make Custom Adapter extending `ArrayAdapter` or `BaseAdapter` in order to achieve your perspective.
- Prepare a layout same as your requirement, ie with 2 `TextViews` and an `ImageView`.
- And, in the `getView` method populate the data as per your requirement.

**[This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown)** might help you in the process.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom ArrayAdapter with a custom view/layout in your case contains two textViews, you can see my [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480269/3996257) with code for create a custom adapter.

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!