# ArrayList of Classes in a ListView on Android and how to update it

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have an ArrayList filled with objects of a class, I try to show it on a ListView but I get something weird in return I get the address of the class like project.Class@"alphanumeric" on the first and only line of the ListView
Here is the code I've got

```
private ListView lvWords;

private Word word;

private pWord pword;

private ArrayList<Word> words;
```

and my onCrete method has this

```
    this.lvWords=(ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.lvWords);

    this.pword=new oWord(this);

    this.words=new ArrayList<Word>();
    this.words=pword.ReturnArrayList();
    ArrayAdapter<Word> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<Word>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);
    this.lvWords.setAdapter(adapter);
```

pword.ReturnArrayList() gets all the words of the database and stores it into a cursor and then each element is converted in a Word object and stored in the array

I'd also like to update it with a button or something

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "first and only line", but have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475434/how-to-use-an-arrayadapter-in-android-of-custom-objects) for the "weird" output. If you mean you're only getting one list item, make sure `ReturnArrayList()` is returning what you expect. That is, check the `size()` of the returned `ArrayList`.

Comment: what is the relation of the size of the array and the ListView? It does return an ArrayList of objects of the Word Class

Comment: The `size()` of the `ArrayList` is the number of items in the `ListView`.

Comment: it still does not display the different attributes that a Word object would have

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. Well, as you read in the linked post, `ArrayAdapter` will display what is returned by an object's `toString()` method, and it will display that in a single `TextView`. If you want all of a `Word`'s attributes in a single `TextView`, you can just alter the `toString()` method to concatenate those attributes as you see fit. If you want a more complicated list item layout - e.g., one with multiple `TextView`s - you will need to implement a custom `Adapter`.

Comment: what I want is each row to be a word and each column an attribute

Comment: Then you will need to implement a custom `Adapter` - or perhaps use a  [`SimpleAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), which I always forget about - with an item layout that uses `LinearLayout`s with weighted `TextView`s. If that's what you're actually asking how to achieve, then I would recommend that you [edit] your question to clarify that. As it is, it just kinda sounds like your main problem was the incorrect `String` output.