# how take details from a class

Tags: class, xamarin

I have a method that gives me back all the films with a particular word inserted by user.
Now I want to copy all the details in one list so, when the user clicks a film that the app shows, it shows a toast with the corresponding ID.

```
How can i do this?

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App_wrapper
{

    public class Result1
    {
        public int vote_count { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool video { get; set; }
        public double vote_average { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public double popularity { get; set; }
        public string poster_path { get; set; }
        public string original_language { get; set; }
        public string original_title { get; set; }
        public List<int> genre_ids { get; set; }
        public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
        public bool adult { get; set; }
        public string overview { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int total_results { get; set; }
        public int total_pages { get; set; }
        public List<Result1> results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Took code from link and inserted it into the post instead, also brushed up the grammar a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Public List<Film> filmList;

public class Film
{
    private String title;
    private String id;

    public Film(String title, String id)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return title;
    }
}


foreach (var paolo in toor.results)
{
 var fItem=new Film{title=paolo.title,id=paolo.id}
 filmList.Add(fItem);
}



RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, filmList);
    lv.Adapter = adapter;
});


//inside ListView_ItemClick

var id_film = filmList.ElementAt(e.Position).id;
```

For reference 
[how to use an ArrayAdapter in android of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475434/how-to-use-an-arrayadapter-in-android-of-custom-objects)

Comment: can i put the public class film inside my main activity? if yes where? inside  "protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)"? or after "before  public class dettagli_film : Activity"

Comment: Don't keep public classes inside Activity. Keep outside where you have your classes like RootObject. I have just given you overview of code.

Comment: ok thanks. I added a new class called film, then i copy Public List<Film> filmList; inside the main activity, and the for each inside the main activiy, but i have error in the foreach. i have film, title and id underlined in red, why? it says me that id and title are not accessible due to the level of protection

Comment: Id & title in film class make public. You should think about these little things.

Comment: try this `var fItem=new Film(paolo.title,paolo.id);`

Comment: don't work. the problem now is in paolo.id. Visual studio says that it is impossibile to convert from int to string. But i changed the class Film. id now is an int and not a string   EDIT: solved i changed the type of id in the RootObject, now is a string

Comment: now i have a new error in the arrayadapter. if i change "dati" with "filmList" it says me that is impossibile to convert from "System.Collection.Generic.List<App_wrapper.ricerca_film.Film > in int. Why?

Comment: inside RunOnUiThread make ArrayAdapter<string> to ArrayAdapter<Film>. Both side left & right.

Comment: last one error i hope. this is my new main activity https://pastebin.com/WfRY8vDu i declered two public  string : film and id at the begin of the main activity, but in the string "var id_film = filmList.ElementAt(e.Position).id;" i have protection error in id variable. why? EDIT RESOLVED

Comment: if i start my application and press the button "ricerca film" i have an exception and the Visual studio program underline this string "lv.Adapter = adapter;" why? here the activity https://pastebin.com/ipteSs3H

Comment: my app is so composed: in the first activity i have 2 botton. one for search any film , second for search any tv series. If i press the first button, the user enter in the activity of the search and the app crash. it give my this error lv.Adapter=adapter; why? Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: Ask this question  J"ava.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' " with your related code. People will try to answer. Don't forget to add code with description like this is "class", "this is listClick evet" etc. Happy coding.

Comment: maybe the problem is the adapter man. i can't do new ArrayAdapter<Film>, maybe i have to build a custom adapter. Is it possible?